# Chaining Shader Effects

Tags: directshow.net, pixel-shader

I wish to create a complex pixel shader effect which cannot be compiled as a single shader effect. So, I'm planning to break down the complex shader effects into multiple shader effects and chain these shader effect files sequentially.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The keywords you are looking for are multi-pass shaders. For chaining, you'll want to look up ping-pong rendering. You may also find using multiple [techniques](http://knol.google.com/k/hlsl-shaders#Technique) (HLSL parlance) useful.